# Analytic vs Zariski neighbourhood of a fibre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\to \mathbb P^1$ be a proper morphism of smooth complex algebraic varieties and let $p\in\mathbb P^1$. Are there a complex disk $\Delta\subseteq\mathbb P^1$ and a Zariski open subset $U\subseteq \mathbb P^1$, with $p\in\Delta\subseteq U$, such that $H^1(f^{-1}(U),{{\mathcal O}^{\rm an}}^*)\to
H^1(f^{-1}(\Delta),{{\mathcal O}^{\rm an}}^*)$ is an injection?

Comment: I believe that fails when $X$ is a general hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3\times \mathbb{P}^1$ of bidegree $(2,d)$, and $p$ is any point of $\mathbb{P}^1$ over which the projection morphism is smooth.

Comment: Could you please expand your comment and explaining why it is not an isomorphism?

Comment: Thank you, I think I have understood your answer now. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the modified question works either. Let $E$ be a general elliptic curve.  Take $X$ to be the quotient of $E\times \mathbb{P}^{1}$ by an involution which is a translation by a point of order 2 on $E$ and is $z \to 1/z$ on $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. Take the map $f : X \to \mathbb{P}^{1}$ that corresponds to the projection $E \times \mathbb{P}^{1} \to \mathbb{P}^{1}$.  Let $p \in \mathbb{P}^{1}$ be a point over which $f$ is smooth, then for any disk $\Delta$ centered at $p$ the analytic Picard group of $f^{-1}(\Delta)$ is just $\text{Pic}(E)$. On the other hand for any Zariski open set $p \in U \subset \mathbb{P}^{1}$ the analytic Picard group of $f^{-1}(U)$ is $\text{Pic}(E')$ where $E'$ is the quotient of $E$ by the point of order 2. Under these identifications the restriction map from the analytic Picard group of $f^{-1}(U)$ to the analytic Picard group of $f^{-1}(\Delta)$ becomes the pullback map
$\text{Pic}(E') \to \text{Pic}(E)$ which has a kernel $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to be sure that I have understood completely your answer: you are using the fact that the analytic Picard group of $f^{-1}(U)$ is the invariant Picard group in $E\times \tilde U$ by the involution, right?

Comment: Yes, this what I had in mind. And the point is that for a Zariski open set $U$, the cover $\widetilde{U}$ is connected while for a small disk $\Delta$, the cover $\widetilde{\Delta}$ has two components.